# Is it possible to update Many to Many relation using automapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have a relation many to many between 2 tables like in below exemple:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonVm
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name {get;set}
        public int[] BookIds { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Book> Books=>_context.Books.Join(BookIds,x=>x.Id,y=>y,(x,y)=>x);
    }
```

then I have the mapping like this:

```
 map.CreateMap<PersonVm, Person>()
 .ForMember(x => x.Books, a => a.MapFrom(b => b.BookIds));
```

And the method which I use for insert or update:

```
public void Update(PersonVm item)
{
    using (IUnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork(new ApplicationDbContext()))
    {
        var oldItem = db.Persons.Get(item.Id);
        var newItem = Mapper.Map<Person>(item);

        if (oldItem == null)
        {
            db.Persons.Add(newItem);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Persons.Update(oldItem, newItem);
        }
        db.Complete();
    }

}
```

With this code I am able to reach the "SaveChanges" point, where I get an error which say that I am not allowed to insert duplicates in Books table (the book table is set to not allow duplicates- no surprise here).

The question is Why entity framework is trying to insert the books?
Can I tell to `EF` to not insert the books in books table?

I only want to insert the Person and to insert data into the Person-Books table.

In my example the person does not exist, must be inserted, the books exist.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Edit: Relation

```
public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
    {
        public PersonMap()
        {
            HasMany(x => x.Books)
                .WithMany(x => x.Persons);
        }
    }
```

and the reverse mapping :

```
map.CreateMap<Person, PersonVm>()
.ForMember(x => x.BookIds, a => a.MapFrom(b => b.Books.Select(c => c.Id).ToArray()));
```

Comment: can you show your `Book` mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use books from mapping, they don't attached. So EF doesn't know that they already exits in database. Iterate by all books and attach them to context. For example:

```
using(var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
  foreach(var book in person.Books)
    context.Books.Attach(book);
}
```

Tip: When item.Id is equal 0 then it doesn't exist in db.

Comment: thanks for Tip, regarding the answer, I do not understand why to attach the books if are already in 'DbContext', can you please give more details

Comment: When you query books from context, then they are attached. But when you create object yourself (mapper do it) they don't attached so you have to inform entity framework that they already exist in database. Check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: @mati: thanks for this answer. This seems like a pretty common use case for automapper (I'm using it in the same way). Do you know if there is any way in automapper to automatically attach any created objects to the `DbContext`?